# What's the difference between standalone and domain on JEE6?

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I'm starting an JBoss to use on the development, and I'm using it as standalone.
I read that on the production environment the JBoss should be as a domain.

I searched for that to understand what's the difference between than. But I didn't found any document well explained.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That's not really correct. Standalone is fine for production. It's commonly used in production, especially when you only need one instance of the server.

Domain is used when you run several instances of JBoss AS and you want a single point where you can control configuration from. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/21/Admin_Guide.html#Operating_modes).

**Update**

The link has been changed to the latest version of WildFly as the JBoss AS 7 documentation has been archived, but is still available at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin%20Guide.html#8094211_AdminGuide-StandaloneServer

Comment: Thanks for that. Just checking. If I want an  clustered EJB, I need to use it as a domain. Right?

Comment: Nope, you can run that from standalone as well. Just use the standalone-ha.xml https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Clustered+EJBs. It might be more typical in a domain environment though. This is definitely not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 19):

**Standalone mode**

- each JBoss server has its own configuration
- single JVM process

**Domain mode**

- central control of multiple servers
- central configuration for multiple servers

Comment: does that mean multiple JVMs can be setup in Domain mode and only one can be setup in standalone mode?

Answer (score 17):

It's important to understand that **the choice between a managed domain and standalone servers is all about how your servers are managed, not what capabilities they have to service end user requests**. This distinction is particularly important when it comes to high availability clusters.

So, given all that:

- A single server installation gains nothing from running in a managed domain, so running a standalone server is a better choice.
- For multi-server production environments, the choice of running a managed domain versus standalone servers comes down to whether the user wants to use the centralized management capabilities a managed domain provides.
- Running a standalone server is better suited for most development scenarios. **Any individual server configuration that can be achieved in a managed domain can also be achieved in a standalone server**, so even if the application being developed will eventually run in production on a managed domain installation, much (probably most) development can be done using a standalone server.

> For the Above explanation and more follow [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Operating+modes?_sscc=t)